# A question in definition of group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In definition  of a group ring $RG$ with elements $∑f_g g$ (where $g\in G$ and $f_g\in R$), are we supposed that $f_g$'s commute with $g$'s? I mean could we identify the above formal summation with $∑ gf_g$? This question arises when working with an involution $*$ in  $RG$ where $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$ for $a,b\in RG$. Thanks to anybody answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The elements of G commute with those of R in the group ring.

Comment: There is a more general construction, that of cross products, in which they do not.

Comment: You wrote that sentence just to fill the minimum character quota, didn't you.

Comment: Yup :-). As I am doing here.